# Using Properties In StyleSheet | React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-stylesheet

I have a horizontal scrolling `ListView` of which I'd like to size the items based on the screens width.

I believe I need to use;

```
const { width } = useWindowDimensions();
```

but I'm unsure of how to use this inside my `StyleSheet`

`width` console logs as correct value.

I was expecting something like;

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  item: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    marginHorizontal: 4,
    backgroundColor: "black",
    borderRadius: 3,
    height: { width / 3 },
    width: { width / 3 },
  },
});
```